# NFS Mount fails on startup

Tags: server, boot, mount, nfs

I have multiple Ubuntu servers, recently I've installed a few 11.04 servers (and 1 desktop) and I've just found that upon rebooting the nfs mounts will not mount.

I've tried upgrading nfs-common to the latest version (I'm only one small revision behind) but that just slightly changes my errors.  All of these servers having the issues are clones (vmWare) from a server template I made awhile back, so I thought maybe it was an issue with the template and therefore all of its clones.  I then tried the same mount on the Desktop 11.04 but I had the same issues.  About half the time I will be able to press "S" to skip but the other half of the time the server freezes (and I restore from a recent snapshot). Also whats odd is that if I *am* able to get into the system then I can do a "mount -a" just fine and it will mount everything. This makes me think the issue is that nfs isn't waiting for a network to be present in order to try mounting.  Something else that makes me think this is that I get a "unable to resolve host" (to an NFS point) error, even though that host is in /etc/hosts.

Here is my /var/log/boot.log

```
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
/dev/sda1 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
/dev/mapper/php53x-root: clean, 75641/1032192 files, 492673/4126720 blocks (check in 5 mounts)
init: portmap-wait (statd) main process (373) killed by TERM signal
init: statd main process (402) terminated with status 1
init: statd main process ended, respawning
init: statd-mounting main process (355) killed by TERM signal
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server NFSSERVER-priv: Name or service not known
init: statd-mounting main process (416) killed by TERM signal
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server NFSSERVER-priv: Name or service not known
init: statd main process (435) terminated with status 1
init: statd main process ended, respawning
init: statd main process (459) terminated with status 1
init: statd main process ended, respawning
mountall: mount /var/www [410] terminated with status 32
mountall: mount /var/users [436] terminated with status 32
init: statd-mounting main process (448) killed by TERM signal
init: statd main process (468) terminated with status 1
init: statd main process ended, respawning
init: statd main process (498) terminated with status 1
init: statd main process ended, respawning
/dev/sda1: 226/124496 files (1.3% non-contiguous), 39133/248832 blocks
mountall: fsck /boot [268] terminated with status 1
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
mountall: mount /var/users [583] terminated with status 32
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
mountall: mount /var/www [575] terminated with status 32
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
mountall: mount /var/www [638] terminated with status 32
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
mountall: mount /var/users [645] terminated with status 32
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
mountall: mount /var/www [724] terminated with status 32
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
mountall: mount /var/users [729] terminated with status 32 Skipping /var/www at user request
 * Starting AppArmor profiles        [80G  [74G[ OK ]
 * Starting Name Service Cache Daemon nscd        [80G  [74G[ OK ]
FATAL: Module vmhgfs not found.
FATAL: Module vmsync not found.
FATAL: Module vmblock not found.
 * Loading open-vm-tools modules        [80G  [74G[ OK ]
 * Starting open-vm daemon vmtoolsd        [80G  [74G[ OK ]
```

Sorry for the long post, just wanted to convey as much information as possible.  Does anyone have any suggestions on this? I've been googling all day and I have tried things with _netdev and well as changing the configuration for statd but nothing has worked. I have 6 servers this is effecting. :\

/etc/fstab: (problem lines only - removing these will allow the rest of nfs to mount)

```
NFSSERVER-priv:/vol/vol1_isp/eshowcase/sites      /var/www       nfs     ro,defaults        0       0
NFSSERVER-priv:/vol/vol1_isp/vusers      /var/users       nfs     defaults        0       0
```

/etc/hosts (relevant entry):

```
10.1.1.43 NFSSERVER-priv
```

Comment: What are your fstab mount lines looking like?

Comment: The problem lines are: (they work just fine on other ubuntu servers on older OSes)

NFSSERVER-priv:/vol/vol1_isp/eshowcase/sites      /var/www       nfs     ro,defaults        0       0

NFSSERVER-priv:/vol/vol1_isp/vusers      /var/users       nfs     defaults        0       0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did as a work around in case anyone else runs into this problem and comes looking for the solution here:

Created a script (mountall.sh) in /etc/init.d/:

```
#!/bin/bash

mount -r NFSSERVER-priv:/vol/vol1_isp/eshowcase/sites /var/www
mount    NFSSERVER-priv:/vol/vol1_isp/vusers          /var/users
```

Make the system aware of the new script:

```
update-rc.d mountall.sh defaults
```

The option “defaults” puts a link to start mountall.sh in run levels 2, 3, 4 and 5. (and puts a link to stop mountall.sh into 0, 1 and 6.)

Chmod the file to be executable

```
chmod +x mountall.sh
```

Now when you init 6 you should have your mount points.  Also a good idea to make a "comment" in your fstab so people know where everything is actually being mounted from as that will be the first place they'll look.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is applicable to you, but the problem [I was having](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377274/mount-a-works-but-boot-hangs-on-mount) was that the directory I was trying to mount at was not available at boot. I instead tried mounting to `/mnt` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue after upgrading ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. Here is what solved the problem for me:

Edit `/etc/default/nfs-common` and make sure it says:

```
NEED_STATD=yes
```

After restarting, my NFS mounts worked.

Answer (score -3):

If you are used window 8 then surely nfs formatted disks will not mount and the answer for this problem is"just again install Windows 8 and disable hibernate option in settings"then only you will able to mount nfs formatted disks.

Comment: If you read the question, he was asking about NFS shares, *not* NTFS shares. Therefore, Windows has nothing to do with this issue at all.