# nfs mount failes on startup

Tags: nfs

After updating to Kubuntu 13.10 (beta) my nfs share stopped auto-mounting during boot.

Here is my fstab:

```
dimanne@Impedance:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system>                           <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=328a9124-e5ff-4c13-a7e2-559ee6a20292 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b3a4a4a4-c563-45c1-9d6b-602b07d66c70 none            swap    sw              0       0
# was on /dev/sdb1
UUID=9383ee42-aea8-4098-9533-08d1b9b04e59 /mnt/backup    ext4   defaults        0       2
# was on /dev/sdc1
UUID=4ad4e84a-1e0e-4cb6-a63a-753d3ffc9ff2 /mnt/freedata ext4    defaults        0       2

server:/mnt/media                       /mnt/media      nfs4    defaults

/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Also I noticed suspicious messages in `dmesg`:

```
dimanne@Impedance:~$ dmesg | grep killed
[   23.436063] init: idmapd-mounting (/mnt/media) main process (455) killed by TERM signal
[   26.828198] init: failsafe main process (1119) killed by TERM signal
[   28.352642] init: kdm main process (1757) killed by TERM signal
```

However if I mount nfs share manually (`sudo mount -vvv server:/mnt/media /mnt/media`) all works perfectly, but at this time I get these messages in dmesg

```
[  458.804009] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[  458.804024] Key type id_resolver registered
[  458.804026] Key type id_legacy registered
[  473.827828] RPC: AUTH_GSS upcall timed out.
[  473.827828] Please check user daemon is running.
```

What is the problem, how can I fix it?

P.S. I have read this [NFS Mount fails on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76901/nfs-mount-fails-on-startup) but there is no solution...

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 the problem can be cured by blacklisting "rpcsec_gss_krb5" module.
Just add "blacklist rpcsec_gss_krb5" at the end of "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf".

Of course, such solution is appropriate if you do not use Kerberos.
You can find more details on this bug [here](https://github.com/manjaro/packages-core/blob/master/linux312/sunrpc-replace-gssd_running-with-more-reliable-check.patch) and [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1001934).

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace "server" with your server's IP address and "/mnt/media" with the shared resource/directory of your server...

Comment: 1)Actually I do not need to replace /mnt/media. This is real path on nfs server (it just coincides with mount-point).
2)Tried to replace dns name to ip - it does not solve problem. There is still the same problem...