# mount -a works, but boot hangs on mount

Tags: boot, 13.10, mount, hard-drive

I have a 3 TB internal HDD (`/dev/sdc`) which I have formatted as NTFS and which is automatically loaded from this `/etc/fstab` file (note, this is an Ubuntu 13.10 OS, not a raspberry pi):

```
UUID=3efd666c-495d-4e95-8094-b1157f5499f3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1                                                                             
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
#UUID=e167c5b7-af0d-4fd5-84de-4c8d86b0303d none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0

# Media drive
/dev/sdc1 /home/raspi/Documents/raspi/raspi/media ntfs rw,suid,dev,auto,exec,nouser,async,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 2
```

With that last line included, the computer hangs when booting, then tells me that the problem is with mounting of `/home/raspi/Documents/raspi/raspi/media` and that I have to press `s` to skip, at which point Ubuntu boots up properly. Once inside, if I issue the command `sudo mount -a`, `sdc1` gets mounted correctly. Does this problem of not being able to mount at boot have something to do with the `uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137` options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the kernel needs the module "ntfs" loaded to mount an ntfs partition. And during bootup this module is not yet loaded.

To configure that the module is mounted add a line with "ntfs" to the file /etc/modules:

```
echo "ntfs" >>/etc/modules
```

Then you can reboot the system and your partition should be mounted.

Comment: just tried it, didn't work

Comment: You could try to use the UUID instead of the device file. Type `blkid` and write this hash instead of /dev/sdc1 like the entry of your ext4 partition. If this does not work, is the path `/home/raspi/Documents/raspi/raspi/media` available at boot time? Try to mount at `/mnt/`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that `/home/raspi/Documents/raspi/raspi/media` was not available at boot